# Probability with permutations?

Tags: probability

Suppose we have a bag with 5 different colored balls. We pick a ball, note its color, then put the ball back inside the bag. We do this 3 times. I want to know the probability of getting 3 balls of the same color.

P(3 balls of same color)=$({1\over 5}\cdot{1\over 5}\cdot{1\over 5})\cdot5={1\over 5}\cdot{1\over 5}$

I see this problem in 2 ways:

1. Pick  a ball (100% chance to pick a color here because you need a color to start with) and now we need P(2 balls of same color as first one)=${1\over 5}\cdot{1\over 5}$
2. Or the first ball had $1\over 5$ probability of being picked, so it's ${1\over 5}\cdot{1\over 5}$ to get 3 balls of the same color, however we could've picked any other ball so multiply the whole probability by 5

Both approaches lead me to the same result $1\over 25$ but I am not sure if both are correct in their reasoning.

Comment: Both seem well-reasoned to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.   The reasoning is sound.

There is an identical probability of selecting any particular colour on any particular draw.   That is $1/5$.

So: (1) It doesn't matter what colour is drawn first, the probability of drawing that colour in the next two draws is $1/5^2$.

Also: (2) The probability of drawing any of the $5$ colours thrice is $5/5^3$.

As you had.   The answer is $1/25$.

Answer (score 1):

Your question comes down to two different ways of working out how to draw the first ball without colour constraint: either the probability of dawing a ball is 1; or the probability of drawing a ball of each colour is $\frac{1}{5}$, since there are 5 colours, the total chance is $\frac{1}{5}*5$, which is 1.

Your calculation is correct in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

1. If I get it correctly, ir doesn't matter to you what the color of the first ball is, as long as the two following balls are the same, ending with a probability of $1\over 25$. If it *is* the case, then it is correct. I would stress that just to be sure.
2. That aspect is more compound, taking all the sub-cases and then adding their probabilities. (Or multiplying the probability of a random color by 5, as the number of every ball in a specific color is the same for all colors, $x=1$. This is why the probability won't be affected if $x$ is different).